# Ficheros y procesos en Java

Tags: java

Estoy creando un simple programa en el que quiero crear un archivo de texto, luego mediante un proceso quiero escribir en el fichero una frase que la introduce el usuario y leer en la consola el contenido del fichero.

El problema es que el proceso me falla según la excepción que creé y no llega a escribir nada en el fichero.

El código del programa es el siguiente:

```
public class ComunicacionProcesos {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner tec = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Escribe un texto con una palabra acentuada");

        String texto = tec.nextLine();

        try {
            File ficheroTexto = new File("texto.txt");

            if (!ficheroTexto.exists()) {
                ficheroTexto.createNewFile();
            }

            System.out.println("Fichero de texto creado");
            
            //Creo el proceso
            ProcessBuilder fichero = new ProcessBuilder("texto.txt");
            //Inicio el proceso
            Process iniciaFichero = fichero.start();

            OutputStream os = iniciaFichero.getOutputStream();
            
            BufferedWriter ficheroEscritura = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os));

            //informacion del padre al hijo
            ficheroEscritura.write(texto);

            System.out.println("Se ha escrito el fichero");
            ficheroEscritura.close();
            
            InputStream is = iniciaFichero.getInputStream();
            
            BufferedReader ficheroLectura = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

            //informacion del hijo al padre
            String linea;

            while ((linea = ficheroLectura.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(linea);
            }

            System.out.println("Lectura realizada");

            ficheroLectura.close();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error al iniciar proceso");
        }
    }
}
```

Estoy aprendiendo a hacer procesos en java así que es muy probable que ahí se encuentre el error. Acepto cualquier sugerencia.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! saca el try, y fijate donde se cuelga y con que error.. un error generico que dice no anda, no sirve para nada, porque no sabes donde es que no anda...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te agrego un ejemplo de como se trabaja con los procesos.

Trabajando en un sistema unix tengo el editor de texto `vi`. Para crear un archivo de texto, escribir en el y guardarlo sigo los siguientes pasos:

1. Abro la terminal.
2. Escribo el comando `vi` seguido del nombre del archivo que quiero crear y luego enter para ejecutar el comando.
3. Presiono `i` para iniciar la inserción de texto en el archivo.
4. Escribo el contenido del archivo : `Hola mundo vi`
5. Para terminar la edición presiono la tecla escape
6. Para guardar los cambios y salir escribo `:wq` y presiono enter.
7. El programa `vi` se cierrra y regreso a la terminal

Los pasos anteriores son los que se deben hacer desde un programa en java que se comunica con un proceso que manipula un archivo de texto, en java sería así:

```
// 1. El paso de abrir la terminal se ignora

// 2. Escribo el comando `vi` seguido del nombre del archivo que quiero crear
// y luego enter para ejecutar el comando.
ProcessBuilder fichero = new ProcessBuilder("vi","/users/carlos/desktop/t9");
Process iniciaFichero = fichero.start();

// conectar a la entrada del proceso
OutputStream os = iniciaFichero.getOutputStream();
BufferedWriter ficheroEscritura = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os));

// 3. Presiono `i` para iniciar la inserción de texto en el archivo.
ficheroEscritura.write("i");
// 4. Escribo el contenido del archivo : `Hola mundo vi`
ficheroEscritura.write("hola mundo vi");
// 5. Para terminar la edición presiono la tecla escape
ficheroEscritura.write(0x1b);
// 6. Para guardar los cambios y salir escribo `:wq` y presiono enter.
ficheroEscritura.write(":wq");
ficheroEscritura.write(System.lineSeparator());

//7. El programa `vi` se cierrra y regreso a la terminal
```